# Why the arraylist's size is 0 even it is full

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an arraylist (user_word).

I send it to CardAdapter2_2_2 and it shows every item that is in the arraylist.

But user_word.size() returns 0. Why?

```
 private DatabaseReference databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("kullanici_kelime");
    private ArrayList<User_word> user_words= new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        databaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                user_words.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User_word user_word= new User_word();
                    user_word.setMean(postSnapshot.child("mean").getValue(String.class)) ;
                    user_word.setName(postSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
                    user_word.setKey(postSnapshot.child("key").getValue(String.class));
                    user_word.setId(postSnapshot.child("id").getValue(String.class));
                    user_word.setDate(postSnapshot.child("date").getValue(Long.class));
                    user_word.setLevel(postSnapshot.child("level").getValue(int.class));
                    user_words.add(user_word);                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();            }        });    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag3, container,false);
        Timestamp ts=new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Date date=new Date(ts.getTime());
        Log.e("size", String.valueOf(user_words.size()));// thats my problem
        adapter= new CardAdapter2_2_2(getActivity(),user_words);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
                return view;
    }
```

Comment: *Why the arraylist's size is 0 even it is full* Because it is empty not full.

Comment: @Antoniossss but cardAdapter shows items in arraylist. how can it be empty?

Comment: It is empty - at the time you check for its size - see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `onCreateView` is called prior to `onStart` and prior to`databaseReference2` calling its `ValueEventListener`s

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure dataSnapshot.getChildern() HAS children and it goes into the for loop.
2. Make sure that onDataChange() gets called.
3. Make sure that onCreateView() gets called after your array is already
   initialized.

Anyway it's hard to tell without having the rest of you code.